# jquery firing events on select

Tags: jquery, select, selected

I'm writing a code in which at the document.ready function im creating dynamically some `<select>` elements with predefined options, each one with a specific id.
(for example #Select1, #Select2,...).

Each time you press a button you can create a new select element. My question is if there is any way in jquery so each time you select an option to be able see what option ive selected and from which select element? Similiar to the `.change()` and `option:selected` jQuery functions but with the only difference is that I dont know the id of the element.

Comment: $(this) . paste your code to understant hot to achive .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#container').on('change', 'select[id^=Select]', function() {

  // get the select id
  console.log(this.id);

  // get the select value
  console.log(this.value); // or $(this).val();

  // To get the selected option's text
  console.log($('option:selected', this).text());
});
```

`#container` is the parent of all `select`s.

`select[id^=Select]` detect all `select`, whose `id` start with `Select`

**NOTE:**

there is nothing like `.selected()` in jQuery.

Comment: @gdoron yup, but `select()` is not for `select` box

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `delegate event` like with `on`:

```
$('#containerId').on('change', 'select', function(){
    this.id // the select id.
    this.value // this is the selected option value
    $(this).val() // this is the selected option value that works in all browsers
});
```

This adds a `change` callback to every `<select>` element under the element with the `containerId` id, no matter when they are created.